# Why does std::span lack the comparison operators?

Tags: c++, std, c++20, std-span

Wasn't the `std::span` designed as a lightweight reference to sub-regions of `std::vector`/`std::array`/*plain array* and alike? Shouldn't it also contain comparison operators in its API, to be consistent with them? What was the reasoning behind the exclusion?

*Note: by comparison operators, I mean either the full set (`<`, `<=`, ...) or the spaceship `<=>`*

Comment: Great question IMO, Im wondering the same. `operator==` is also missing. Esp. for vector I often find it convenient to compare directly. It could be due to difficulties perhaps with the static size span types, although Im not sure.

Comment: It looks like gsl::span, from which std::span is versioned from doesn't include these either.

Comment: The problem might be in the _element-comparison operator_. How should it be defined? Hard-coding `operator<` or `std::less` likely would not be the best approach. A template argument of `std::span`? How should it be defined for non-comparable value types? Template argument of a span comparison operator? Note that, e.g., `std::string_view` has _character traits_ for this purpose.

Comment: @DanielLangr why not a lexicographical comparison like `std::vector` and  `std::array` do? They're defined just like that for those types already, so why not here.

Comment: @Time You're right, it would likely work. It basically works as `std::lexicographical_compare`, which uses `operator<` by default.

Comment: Note that [P0122R7](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0122r7.pdf) proposes comparison for `span`, but the [current draft standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/views) does not include it.

Comment: @darune `gsl::span` _does_ (and always did) have comparison operators. They just moved them into their [own header](https://github.com/microsoft/GSL/blob/master/include/gsl/span_ext)

Comment: Plain arrays certainly do not have these comparisons (except by address, which `<=>` excludes for being confusing).

Answer (score 13):

[As Daniel Langr pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60633668/why-does-stdspan-lack-the-comparison-operators#comment107273050_60633668), `std::span` has  comparison operators in its initial proposal [P0122](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0122r7.pdf). These operators are then removed since the working draft [N4791](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2018/n4791.pdf), and the reasons are stated in [P1085](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1085r2.md).

In short, copy and const for `std::span` are "shallow" (meaning copying a `std::span` doesn't copy its underlying elements, and a const `std::span` doesn't prevent its underlying elements from being modified), so comparisons, if exist, should also be "shallow" for consistency.

That paper gives the following examples:

Example 1:

```
T oldx = x;
change(x);
assert(oldx != x);
return oldx;
```

Example 2:

```
void read_only(const T & x);

void f()
{
  T tmp = x;
  read_only(x);
  assert(tmp == x);
}
```

The assertions in these examples may fail if `T = std::span`, while it doesn't for regular types.

One may argue that `std::string_view` has shallow copy but deep comparisons. P1085 also has an explanation for this:

> This matches `string_view`, however `string_view` can't modify the elements it points at, and thus the shallow copy of `string_view` can be thought of as similar to a copy-on-write optimization.

Comment: Note that nothing prevents the owner of character array to modify the original storage while `std::string_view` points to it. So, say, `std::map<std::span<T>, U>` is as broken as `std::map<std::string_view, U>`. IMHO, `std::string_view` shouldn't contain comparison operators either.

Comment: Follow up: Both examples would work for `T = std::span<const U>` for some other template parameter `U`. Wouldn't `operator==` be reasonable for this case? Has this been considered as well?

Comment: A `span<const T>` does not have the described problem.

Comment: Surely we don't expect `==` on a span to compare the values of elements given the definition of `std::span operator=` and the basic intent of `std::span`. I'm not sure I see why `==` was removed entirely rather than being a shallow comparison `==`. This really limits the usefulness of this class.