# Why C++20 knows how to hash string_view, but does not know how to hash span<char>?

Tags: c++, c++20, string-view, std-span

My best guesses are that committee either forgot about this use case or did not want to use concepts/requires to restrict the `span` type to something that can be safely hashed(POD, no padding), or they did not want half solutions(waiting for reflection)...

If somebody is interested here is [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/9WWe3srMM) link with unhelpful error messages and code, but I presume my question is clear without any code.

```
#include <span>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <string_view>
int main() {
    std::hash<std::string_view> h1;
    std::hash<std::span<char>> h2; // error here
}
```

note: I know C++ `std::` library is lacking in cases when it comes to hashing, e.g. it can not hash `std::pair<int,int>`, but my question is in particular about the `std::span`.

Comment: `std::string_view` is a view to a string, and having a hashing functions for strings was agreed to.  `std::span<char>` is like a `std::vector<char>`.  It might have a string in it, or it could be binary payload for something.  What hashing to use here is less straight forward.

Comment: @NathanOliver AFAIK there is nothing illegal about having a string_view with any content in it, or are you refering to something else(like what hash has good properties for common text patterns)? https://godbolt.org/z/5drn7se4q

Comment: Sure, there is no actual rule, but why use a `string_view` for something other than a view into a string?  Using it's type to convey intention is great for self documentation.  Ans yes, my distiction is there are hashes out there that are good for text, and since `string_view` *should* have text in it, it makes sense to have a hasher for it.  `span<char>`  OTOH can represent anything, and that may or may not need a different type of hashing.  For me that is ambiguity enough not to provide a hasher, just like we don't have one for `vector<char>` or `array<char, N>`

Answer (score 2):

`string_view` is very definitely a string; a `span<char>` is just an array of `char`s. It *could* have the same conceptual meaning as a `string_view`, but you cannot say that this is inherently true of the type. And therefore, it is not reasonable for the standard to assume that every `span<char>` ought to be treated equivalently to a string.

Most containers don't have standard-defined hashing (the string containers being the only exception). The reason being that there's not a good default hash algorithm for a sequence of `T`s. And even if there was, `span<char>` using that algorithm almost certainly wouldn't produce the same hashed value as a `string_view`.

Furthermore, the two types treat equivalency differently. `string_view` has an `operator==` overload; `span<T>` does not. Hashing is conceptually based on equality: if two objects compare equal, then the hashes produced by those objects must be equal. But since `span` has no equality testing at all, hashing a `span` makes little sense.

Comment: This sort of just expands the question to why span doesn't have `operator==`. As far as I can tell, there is no reason for this absence. The comparable type in other languages (e.g., Rust's or Swift's slice, etc.) all have eq and hashing, and in some cases ordering and so on.

Comment: @GManNickG I could point you to the paper that removed it, but honestly it's a pretty bad decision made in response to a pretty bad paper and we're all worse off for it.

Comment: @Barry Sounds about right for the committee. I came across https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60633668/why-does-stdspan-lack-the-comparison-operators which discusses it more and links to various papers.

Comment: @Barry is this related? https://abseil.io/blog/20180531-regular-types